# Show map on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am developing an iOS application and I want to post map of user location on Facebook. I can get user location and post on Facebook using the Facebook API. But I want to post a map on Facebook like in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: Does any body have idea. how can i do this?